# Inequality proof: $3^n(n-1)!>n^n$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following-

$$3^n(n-1)!>n^n$$

$\forall n\ge2$

I have done it using standard induction hypothesis. Can someone suggest some other method?

Comment: Maybe to try a Stirling approximation?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you do it by induction?

Answer (score 1):

$3^n(n-1)!>n^n
$
is the same as
$3^nn!>n^{n+1}
$.

Since
$n! > (n/e)^n$,
$3^nn!
\gt 3^n(n/e)^n
=n^n(3/e)^n
$
so we need
$(3/e)^n
\ge n$.

or
$n\ln(3/e)
\ge \ln(n)
$
which is true,
according to Wolfy,
 for
$n \ge 
 e^{-W_{-1}(1 - \log(3))}
\approx 36.47
$.

We can get a more elementary upper bound
by using
$\ln(n)
\lt \sqrt{n}
$.

This is true when
$n\ln(3/e)
\ge \sqrt{n}
$
or
$\sqrt{n}
\ge \dfrac1{\ln(3)-1}
\approx 10.14
$
or
$n \ge 103
$.

Answer (score 1):

[Not a good solution, but it improves somewhat on the case checking]

WTS $ 3^n \times n! > n^{n+1} $

Taking logs on both sides,
WTS $  n \log 3 + \sum_{i=1}^n \log n > (n+1) \log n$.

Since $\log$ is an increasing function, we have $ \sum_{i=1}^n \log n > \int_{1}^{n} \log x \, dx = [x (\log x - 1) ] _1^n = n \log n - n + 1$.

WTS $ 1+ n  \log 3/e > \log n $

Since the LHS is linear, it will eventually win out, and does when $n \geq 21 $.

So, it remains to check all smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

$$3^n(n-1)!>n^n\implies \frac{3^n(n-1)! }{n^n } >1 \implies \log\left(\frac{3^n(n-1)! }{n^n } \right) > 0$$ Expand the logarithm and use Stirling approximation and you then need to prove that
$$f(n)=n \log \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2 \pi }{n}\right)+\frac{1}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) >0$$ To minimize the lhs, compute its derivative
$$f'(n)=\log \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}$$ which cancels at 
$$n_*=\frac{3+\sqrt{3 \left(3+4 \log \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)\right)}}{12 \log
   \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)}\approx 5.23188\implies f(n_*)\approx 0.623409$$

But, the second derivative test shows that this point corresponds to a minimum. Then, the inequality holds for all $n \geq 0$.